# ReferenceError: Strict mode forbids implicit creation of global property in for loop on promise

Tags: javascript, q

I am having a really strange problem. I am trying to perform a for loop on a promise return value. When I run the code from a jasmine test it breaks. When I run it from a browser it breaks. The code is....

```
courseService.getCourseDates(8).then(function (data) {

            console.log(data[0]);  --this works
            console.log(data[1]);  --this works

            for (s in data) {
                console.log(data[s]);
            }
}
```

**Expected** output:

```
'2014-06-14T00:00:00'
'2014-06-14T00:00:00'
'2014-06-14T00:00:00'
'2014-06-14T00:00:00'
```

**Actual** output from Karma/Jasmine:

> ReferenceError: Strict mode forbids implicit creation of global
>   property 's'

**Actual** Output from browser:

```
ReferenceError: s is not defined
```

Anyone know what is wrong? I have used for loops like this in the past and clearly the array is being populated okay....

Comment: What's not clear about `s is not defined`??

Comment: well s should contain a date shouldn't it?

Comment: The **variable** is not defined, not its value. There is no `var` declaration for it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (var s in data) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: oh that's funny I have used it without the var s before in other code :-/ I will accept the answer :-)

Comment: I suspect that when you’ve used it without ever declaring the variable with `var`, you were not using strict mode.