# Why do class embedded loops appear to follow different assignment rules?

Tags: javascript, class, for-loop

Alright so here's a class with a six item array in the constructor.

```
class forLoopProblem {

  constructor() {
    this.a = [5,8,7,4,6,18];
  }
```

What I want to do is use the length of the array to limit the number of iterations in the `for` loop below

```
  iterate(ap1) {
    for (i = 0; i <= this.a.length; i++) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}

var internalVar = new forLoopProblem();
```

Unfortunately `internalVar.iterate()` produces an exception stating that `a` is not defined.

```
  log() {
    console.log(this.a.length);
    console.log(this.a);
  }
}

var internalVar = new forLoopProblem();
```

But if `a` is not defined then why does `internalVar.log()` behave as expected, printing `6` along with the contents of the array to the console?

At first I thought perhaps `6` is a string that needs to be converted to an integer before the loop assignment will recognize it. So I tried `parseInt()` but that didn't work. And anyway the exception says that the variable isn't defined, so I don't think it's a parsing issue.

I can even use `a` to assign the initial iteration variable to 6, like so:

```
    for (i = this.a.length; i <= 10; i++) {
```

to produce `6`,`7`,`8`,`9`, and `10` as console output.

So what gives with the limiter specification?

Comment: Please fix *all* the typos in your code before posting it here.

Comment: I only see one, where I misspelled iterate. And as long as it's consistent that shouldn't matter.

Comment: `itterate`, `interate`, `lenth`… And I hope the forgotten declaration of the `i` variable is a typo as well.

Comment: Oh I see those now. Will correct. But no, as it turns out the forgotten declaration of i was not a typo. The official JavaScript tutorial fails to mention that the i must be declared. And in literally every situation different from this, I've never been required to declare it. So I had no idea. And I'm currently trying to figure out the why of it.

Comment: Well you just a had lot of luck… not declaring variables makes them global, and in iterations that can easily lead to infinite loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, though i had to define `i` in the for-loop:

JavaScript

```
class forLoopProblem {
  constructor() {
    this.a = [5,8,7,4,6,18];
  }
  itterate(ap1) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.a.length; i++) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}

var internalVar = new forLoopProblem();
internalVar.itterate(); //0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Tested in:

- Chrome - Works
- Firefox - Works
- Opera - Works
- IE10 - Does not work
- Safari (Win8) - Does not work

Comment: That worked thanks. Why do you think that makes a difference though? I've never needed to declare i as a variable in any other situation.

Comment: Maybe inside ES6 `class` you have to? (Just guessing).

Comment: [classes are strict mode code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29285330/1048572), and if you [assign to an undeclared variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) that is an exception. It should show up in the error console ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23549062/1048572)).